# Commands to get offline logs from wp7 using WPConnect?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, error-logging

I know that we can get offline logs from WP7 devices using WPConnect tool. But i have forgotten the commands and also forgotten the site address from where i had learnt it. Does anyone know what are those commands. I have the following code to log offline exceptions, but i don't know how to retrieve the log file.. Please help.

```
  #region Offline Error Logger
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs Exception for the app when the device is not connected to the PC.This file can later be retrieved for the purpose of Bug fixing 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strMsg">Exception message</param>
    private static void LogOffline(string strMsg)
    {
```

## if LOG_ENABLED

```
        try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                string dirName = "SOSLog";
                string logFileName = "SOSLog.txt";
                string fullLogFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(dirName, logFileName);
                // TODO: Synchronize this method with MainPage using Mutex
                string directoryName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fullLogFileName);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(directoryName) && !myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists(directoryName))
                {
                    myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Created directory");
                }
                if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(fullLogFileName))
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream =
                            myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(fullLogFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(strMsg);
                            writer.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream =
                            myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(fullLogFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(strMsg);
                            writer.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception while logging: " + ex.StackTrace);
        }
```

## endif

```
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this: [Error Reporting on Windows Phone (Little Watson)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2010/11/01/error-reporting-on-windows-phone-7.aspx)?

Comment: Once the logging is done you can actually fetch the isolated storage files from the device or emulator and store it on your PC.. You need to use WPConnect for it and then use come commands to get it... I have done it before but i have forgotten the commands!!!

Comment: I got the solution..My question is partially wrong am editing it soon